# SQL Subtract From Value

Tags: mysql, lua, subtraction

I've got a question, this is my query:

```
unique_id = LocalPlayer():GetNWString ("SteamID")
sql.Query("UPDATE player_info SET money = money - 5 WHERE unique_id = '"..unique_id.."'")
```

It's mysqlite and LUA, I need it to subtract "x" amount of money when executed.

Calling the function

```
function PlayerInitialSpawn( ply )

    timer.Create("SteamIDDelay", 1, 1, function()
        SteamID = ply:SteamID()
        ply:SetNWString("SteamID", SteamID)
    timer.Create("SaveStats", 10, 0, function() SaveStats( ply ) end)
        PlayerExists( ply ) 
        ply:ChatPrint( "Stats Saved!" )
    end)

end
```

Save stat function

```
function SaveStats ( ply )

    money = ply:GetNWInt("money")
    unique_id = ply:GetNWString ("SteamID")
    sql.Query("UPDATE player_info SET money = "..money.." WHERE unique_id = '"..unique_id.."'")

end
```

Comment: Is that not working? Are you getting an error? Are you sure `unique_id` will never contain a single-quote?

Comment: I know it doesn't, this is the save stats function. Update original post.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? (Also aren't you printing `Stats Saved!` too early? (Not that that matters here.))

Comment: Yeah every 10 seconds, but it seems to not even print it every 10 seconds. (it was for testing) My question is, why doesn't the subtraction from the original value work? I click the button which runs the function to take away the $5 and it doesn't do anything, nor does it give me any LUA errors.

Comment: Can you run that statement by hand and have it work? Are you sure the statement is being run?

Comment: I'm coding in a game called Garry's Mod, and on my HUD I have it so it uses a "button on click" function, and once the button is clicked it runs whatever is within the function, so I have no reason to believe it wouldn't work, plus if anything is wrong within the function once I click the button it'll give me a LUA error.

Comment: What's the result of the `sql.Query` function call? Does it return anything?

Comment: Well if the original query that sets the money when it's the players first time in the server works then that query should. It's the same, just instead of - 5 it sets to 5000 (which works)

Comment: Where does `ply:GetNWInt("money")` get the value it returns from? How are you checking whether the subtraction function works?

Comment: It gets the money int from the code/database I believe. All I know is that it works since it displays the 5,000 starting money on the HUD without error. And if the function were to not work it'd give me a lua error, but instead it doesn't give anything (which usually means it works) when I get back home (at work rn) I'll show you the whole code and we could probably talk on Skype or whatever you have.

(I don't understand all of the LUA yet since I'm just starting at LUA.)

Comment: If savestats doesn't get the money from the db then every ten seconds you'll be resetting the database to whatever value that `GetNWInt` function returns.

Comment: Well to see my code and to get further help I'll need to be at home looking at it, do you have any way I can further contact you in a few hours?

Comment: Post a comment here. I'll get notified about it.

Comment: Okay. I'll be back within a few hours, thanks for your continued help.

Comment: I'm back, here's the whole database functions http://pastebin.com/xMJzMcVm

Comment: Also, heres proof that it actually saves: http://prntscr.com/70fur8

Comment: Where does `SQLValueStats` get `steamID` from? Why are you selecting for both `unique_id` and `money` in `PlayerExists` and then selecting for them *again* in `SQLValueStats`? Where does the subtraction function fit in to this code? Why are you trying that query instead of just setting the `NWInt` money value and then using `SaveStats`?

Comment: This was a default code given that I just edited a bit, and steamID is integrated into the base code of the game, which grabs the users SteamID (ignore that) and unique_id and money need to both get called/named (forget how to explain) so that when it's called in a later function it actually works.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/70fz4k I believe that's how it works. Correct me if I'm wrong.. lol top text says "when unique_id is called it runs that"

Comment: You are suggesting that `GetNWString("SteamID") is calling `SQLValueStats`? I don't think that's likely. `steamID` is clearly some sort of global (you assign to it somewhere else in the code I believe) but that seems a weird way to do things (not safe for multiple users/etc.) `SQLValueStats` pulls values from the SQL db and stores them on the player with `SetNW*` functions so that later calls to the `GetNW*` functions (presumably) get the new values.

Comment: I don't understand the flow or environment well enough to know that I can direct you the right way. I also don't have time now I have to disappear. There are probably better GMod-specific forums you can ask on also.

Comment: Well what seems "necessary"?